# Laptop power button on a Acer Aspire no longer shuts the machine down

Tags: windows

The power button of my 18-month-old Acer Aspire laptop has suddenly stopped working. I have messed around with changing the power settings, rebooting, the troubleshooters, etc.  Nothing yet.

I now notice that the list of Advanced Power Settings doe not include the Power buttons and lid setting.

Any assistance most appreciated.

Comment: I gave you a truly good answer to get going with and it was deleted. I cannot help you now.

Comment: @john I can see your answer below - the system thinks you deleted it? I've voted to undelete but I'm only 1 person. Hopefully others do so as well, otherwise I can copy your answer and repost - but that would make it mine???

Comment: You can copy the answer and make it yours.  Good luck.

Comment: Thanks.  I have made all the various changes to the settings, and it still doesn't work.  I've also followed all the suggestions I've found on other help forums. The fact that the "Power buttons and lid" setting is missing from the Advanced Settings is likely indicative of the problem.

Comment: Install the latest video driver for your laptop, reboot, see if this returns the settings.

Comment: Thank you -- I did install 5 or 6 of the "optional updates", including one that was an Intel "Display" update.  Button now works properly again.  I wonder if I should install the 7 or 8 other "optional updates".  What do other folks do with regards to the optionals?

Answer (score 0):

I've had this happen.  If this is a hardware issue, use the operating system to shut down.  You also might have a setting that says what the button does.  You can often say what each button does in windows when the laptop is plugged in and not plugged in.  That can be found in the control panel.  Check those to make sure that they don't say, "Go to sleep when the laptop is plugged in. It can be something like that.  Obviously, if it is a hardware issue, to the shop it goes.."